# Python how to do this scipy sparse matrix addition?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to perform the following operation :

```
A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([0,15,0,0,2,3])

B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1,0,10,0,2,3])

C = operation(A,B)
```

where the result should be scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1,15,10,0,2,3])

Briefly, i want to add two sparse matrix (vectors in fact but w.e) such that

1. if A[i] == B[i] then C[i] = A[i] = B[i];
2. if A[i] == 0 and B[i] != 0 then C[i] = B[i];
3. if A[i] != 0 and B[i] == 0 then C[i] = A[i]

The way i'm currently performing it is quiet slow so i would like to know if you guys know of a way to do this fast :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the way you're currently performing it?

Comment: What about if `A[i] != B[i]` and not 0?  Or does that case never occur?

Comment: @P. Camilleri I'm currently iterating on both A and B by calling zip.

Comment: @hpaulj The case you mention does not happen with my data :)

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, it seems that you are looking for the elementwise maximum of the matrices ? I don't think there's a built-in way to do this with sparse matrices (using np.maximum would be memory expensive).

You can use the equivalence max(a, b) = (a + b + |a - b|) / 2

So: `C = (A + B + np.absolute(A - B)) / 2`

Comment: I did not thought about elementwise maximum but that is clearly what i want! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I used to be able to apply `update` to `dok` format, but that's now been disabled.

The best I can do, for now is:

```
In [49]: d = dict(A.todok())
In [50]: d.update(B.todok())
In [51]: d
Out[51]: {(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 15, (0, 2): 10, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 3}
```

But I don't, offhand, see a quick way of building a `dok` dictionary from this regular one.  (I'd have to study the `dok` code more).

The `coo` format is a good one for constructing new matrices.  Unfortunately it sums duplicates.

```
In [61]: Ac = A.tocoo()
In [62]: Bc = B.tocoo()
In [63]: rows = np.concatenate([Ac.row, Bc.row])
In [64]: cols = np.concatenate([Ac.col, Bc.col])
In [65]: data = np.concatenate([Ac.data, Bc.data])
In [66]: C = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows, cols)))
In [67]: C.A
Out[67]: array([[ 1, 15, 10,  0,  4,  6]], dtype=int32)
```

Which is the same as `(A+B).A`

@p-camilleri's calculation might well be the best:

```
In [70]: (A + B + np.absolute(A-B))/2
Out[70]: 
<1x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [71]: _.A
Out[71]: array([[ 1., 15., 10.,  0.,  2.,  3.]])
```

(`_.A` is the array representation of the last result.)

Comment: nitpick: _.A might be deserve an additional comment, because the two input matrices are called A and B.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and answer :)